# Why does my ListView crash my app instead of listing my Entries?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I`m a Android Beginner and I copied some code together to get my first simple ListView.
But it doesn't work. Instead of working, it crashes my app.
Any help to get my ListView correctly to work would be immensely appreciated, thank you.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.listview_test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // Array of strings...
    ListView simpleList;
    String countryList[] = {"India", "China", "australia", "Portugle", "America", "NewZealand"};

    @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        simpleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.textView, countryList);
        simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error logs**

```
11-08 10:01:59.277 3676-3676/com.example.listview_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.listview_test, PID: 3676
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:75)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:701)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:760)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2481)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1289)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1197)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:785)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:654)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:785)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:654)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2755)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2438)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6742)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:826)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:629)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:597)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:812)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5929)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:75) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:701) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425) 
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2481) 
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1289) 
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1197) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:785) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:654) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:785) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:654) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2755) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2438) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1418) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6742) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:826) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:629) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:597) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:812) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5929) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:604)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3804)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:685)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:680)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:676)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:75) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:701) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425) 
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2481) 
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1289) 
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1197) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:785) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:654) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:785) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:654) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5710) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2755) 
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17970) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2438) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1418) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6742) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:826) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:629) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:597) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:812) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5929) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Comment: share error log..

Comment: When your app is crashing, your first reflex - yes, before posting on StackOverflow - is to check the Logcat to see what happenned

Comment: Try to remove `android:padding="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`. If you want to use `padding` then you can try `android:padding="8dp"`.

Comment: Removing android:padding="@mipmap/ic_launcher" puts ListView to work. Its nearly unformated, but its a ListView. Thanks very much....

Comment: The line android:padding="@mipmap/ic_launcher" cuases crash here, update the padding with some numeric value. Will solve the problem

Comment: Aaaah...now I understand! I had a imageurl as a padding in my code! That was a silly mistake from me of course, causing on copy, paste and delete the wrong things. Thank you all very much for your help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:padding="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`
this line in your activity_listView.xml is causing the error.

```
`android:padding="any numeric value dp"`
```

ex     `android:padding="5dp"`

remove `@mipmap/ic_launcher` from the padding attribute and add as mentioned above.

Comment: Who can say to me, where in the errorlog I could have seen, what the error for the crash is?

Comment: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView.Your error says that you have an issue in an XML file at line no. 7 on defining TextView.As you have entered the wrong attribute inside TextView thats why it is showing error in TextView.Just read the error log's first two lines where they mentioned the cause as well as location of error.

Comment: Also, try to understand all the important  attributes and their values for all Views. Every view has some commonly used attributes. There are so many tutorials from where you can understand them.

Answer (score 0):

In your `activity_listview` change your `padding` value of your `TextView` like below

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
  <!-- modify below line like below -->
   android:padding="5dp" 
/>
```